# About Times Higher Education world university ranking

Tags: university, ranking

Recently I have received an invitation from Times Higher Education to participate in their world university ranking survey. In the email it has been said that participation is based on invitation only. I am wondering what has made them sending this invitation ? I have no experience of taking part in this participation. Can I write this in my academic cv ?